# Jupyter/IPython seems to change the dimensions of Matplotlib graphs when sending to a frontend

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter

I have developed a custom frontend that uses Jupyter/IPython. The frontend is developed in Qt/PyQt. It works very well. I use `%matplotlib inline` and regularly generate matplotlib graphs and they get sent from the kernel as png images to the frontend as a sequence of bytes. I can then display the graphs as static png images on my frontend.

I'd really like to be able to interact with the static images, so if I click on a point in the image, I can then send those pixel coordinates to the kernel and have it convert the pixel coordinates to data coordinates (display coordinates in Matplotlib terminology). In theory this is possible using the matplotlib axes. eg. `ax.transData.inverted().transform(pixel_coordinate_x, pixel_coordinate_y)`.

However, it's not working for me properly. The display coordinates it returns don't match the point(s) I select on the static graph. Eventually I figured out that the png image that I'm receiving is not the same size as the plot I'm telling matplotlib to generate. So if I say `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))`, a 6"x4" image is generated and if I query the dimensions on the kernel it returns the correct dimensions, but I might get back a 5.3"x3.5" png at the frontend.

I have tried changing the matplotlib rcParams for *savefig.dpi* to 80 dpi to match the display settings, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. eg. `plt.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 80.0` and I also am now specifying the dpi for the figure when I'm creating it: `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4), dpi=80.0)`.

Out of desperation I've been printing all sorts of figure and axes settings to see if there is anything that could point out where I'm going wrong, and I spotted that if I display `ax.bbox.corners()`, it returns a numpy array with coordinates like this:

```
[[ 60.   40.]
[ 60.  288.]
[432.   40.]
[432.  288.]]
```

I've been treating the first row as offsets for the x and y pixel coordinates (eg. [60.  40.]) and I thought that seemed to be helping, but now I'm not sure.

Here's some simple code to generate a graph:

```
plt.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 80.0
import random

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4), dpi=80.0)
x = range(0, 10)
y = [random.random() for i in x]
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo-')
ax = fig.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_label_text('YVAL')
fig.set_facecolor('#ff0000')
print fig.bbox.corners()
print ax.bbox.corners()
```

The figure size in pixels should be 480x320 (from 6" x 80 dpi, 4" x 80 dpi), but when I look at the png file in this case I get 429x283. I found the code below seems to show the image size:

```
img = IPython.core.pylabtools.print_figure(fig))
from PyQt4.QtGui import QImage
img2 = QImage.fromData(img)
print img2.width()
print img2.height()
```

Really I'm grasping at straws now, so if there are any experts in Matplotlib/Jupyter/IPython who can help me, I'd really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's quite likely, in `ipykernel`, file `ipykernel/pylab/config.py` you 'll see

```
rc = Dict({'figure.figsize': (6.0,4.0),
    # play nicely with white background in the Qt and notebook frontend
    'figure.facecolor': (1,1,1,0),
    'figure.edgecolor': (1,1,1,0),
    # 12pt labels get cutoff on 6x4 logplots, so use 10pt.
    'font.size': 10,
    # 72 dpi matches SVG/qtconsole
    # this only affects PNG export, as SVG has no dpi setting
    'figure.dpi': 72,
    # 10pt still needs a little more room on the xlabel:
    'figure.subplot.bottom' : .125
    },
    help="""Subset of matplotlib rcParams that should be different for the
    inline backend."""
).tag(config=True)
```

You *should* be able to set `c.InlineBackend.rc=dict()` in one of your config file to disable this. InlineBackend also appear to be singleton so you might be able to get a handle to it and modify its rc values pretty easily.

Note that matplotlib itself also check whether it's in IPython and may do changes as well.

And yes, some of those setting likely need to be removed now that hi-dpi screens are more common it's a regular issue.